# the difference between two style of inline ASM

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly

My code print FAIL as follow:

Need someone to explain the difference.

I want to know the difference between

```
__asm__ __volatile__(
    "addl %1,%0;"
    :"=r"(sum)
    :"r"(add1),"r"(add2)
);
```

and

```
__asm__ ( "addl %%ebx, %%eax;"
     : "=a" (sum)
     : "a" (add1), "b" (add2) );
```

My source code:

```
    int sum = 0;
    int add1 = 100;
    int add2 = 200;

#ifdef __x86_64__
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "addl %1,%0;"
        :"=r"(sum)
        :"r"(add1),"r"(add2)
    );

    // __asm__ ( "addl %%ebx, %%eax;"
    //     : "=a" (sum)
    //     : "a" (add1), "b" (add2) );

#else
    sum = add1 + add2;
#endif
```

Comment: `"addl %1,%0;" :"=r"(sum):"r"(add1),"r"(add2)`is telling the compiler to use 3 different registers in the inline assembly. The inline assembly of course only uses 2 of them and the third is unused. `__asm__ ( "addl %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (sum) : "a" (add1), "b" (add2) );` uses 2 registers. The same register EAX for input and output and EBX for input. This would use 2 different registers the compiler picks `__asm__ ( "addl %2, %0;" : "=r" (sum) : "0" (add1), "r" (add2) );`  . The `"0"(add1)` input tell compiler to use same register as the 0th operand which is `"=r"(sum)`